# Leer un fichero linea por linea

Tags: c++, string, archivo

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en **C++** en el cual me van a dar los datos en un archivo llamado **Entrada.txt** el cual pasara los datos así.

```
3
V20483031154 50
U64329085364 50
V20487646102 50
2
V2048
U
```

Quiero saber como puedo guardar cada uno de los seriales que me pasan en una variable string distinta, pues yo uso getline y me pone todo lo que esta dentro del archivo txt en el string.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    ifstream archivo;
    string texto;

    archivo.open("Entrada.txt",ios::in); //Abrimos el archivo en modo lectura

    if(archivo.fail()){
      cout<<"No se pudo abrir el archivo";
      exit(1);
    }

    while(!archivo.eof()){ //mientras no sea final del archivo
      getline(archivo,texto);
      cout<<texto<<endl;

    }

    archivo.close();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No comprendo realmente lo que necesitas; debes ser mas claro,  si es necesario poner un ejemplo de lo que quieres obtener, para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Que tienes hecho hasta el momento? Si cuelgas el código podremos ayudarte mejor. Gracias.

Comment: Inglese, pero: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: `system("pause")` no es idea buena en una aplicacion de consola (en general): No es la tarea de tu aplicacion de quedar una ventana abierta; a lo peor, eso impide que se pueda usar la aplicacion en un archivo batch...

Answer (score 2):

> Una solución es utilizar un **arreglo de string** para ir colocando cada
>   linea del archivo en cada elemento del arreglo así podrás obtener cada
>   linea de texto del archivo. Seria de esta manera:

:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<fstream.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int c=0 ;        //contador de lineas del archivo
char linea[200];      //guardara cada linea del archivo, hasta un maximo de 200 lineas

//Abrimos el archivo y contamos la cantidad de lineas con informacion y guardamos en la variable "c"
ifstream leer_archivo("D:\\Entrada.txt",ios::in);
while(!leer_archivo.eof()){
 leer_archivo.getline(linea,100);
 c++;
 }
leer_archivo.close();


string *texto = new string[c];       //creamos un vector de string con la cantidad de lineas del archivo guardado en "c"
c=0;
ifstream archivo("D:\\Entrada.txt",ios::in);    //abrimos nuevamente el archivo(aqui pones la direccion de tu artivo)
while(!archivo.eof()){
     archivo.getline(linea,100);      //el 100 es la cantidad de caracteres por linea ,puedes aumentar si necesitas
     texto[c]=linea;
     c++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
    cout<<""<<texto[i].c_str()<<endl;     //cada texto[i] contiene una linea del archivo
}

archivo.close();

getch();     //es para evitar que se cierre la consola, es mejor que system("pause");debes importar:  #include <conio.h>
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez usando la función `getline` de esta manera, te funcione.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    std::vector<std::string> seriales;
    std::ifstream entrada;
    std::string linea;
    entrada.open("archivo.txt", std::ios::in);

    //Usamos un bucle while para leer línea a línea
    while(getline(entrada, linea)){
        //Guardamos en el vector usando el método "push_back"
        seriales.push_back( linea );

        //Imprimís en pantalla
        std::cout "Línea: " << linea << std::endl;
        linea = "";
    }
    entrada.close();
    return 0;
}
```